# Не удается вызвать функцию GetFileTime

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Не могу вызвать функцию

```
GetFileTime(hFile, FILETIME, FILETIME, FILETIME);
```

Вот мой кусочек кода:

```
SYSTEMTIME lf;
FILETIME ft;
OFSTRUCT of;
HANDLE hFile=(HANDLE)OpenFile(lpMyString, &of, OF_CREATE);

GetFileTime(hFile, &ft, NULL, NULL);
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, &lf);
```

Ошибка в следующем:

> error C2668: 'Postup::GetFileTime' : ambiguous call to overloaded
>   function

Тогда я пытаюсь явно указать тип:

> error C2668: 'Postup::GetFileTime' : ambiguous call to overloaded
>   function 1>          c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\postup\postup\Form1.h(19): could be 'BOOL
>   Postup::GetFileTime(HANDLE,LPFILETIME,LPFILETIME,LPFILETIME)' 1>
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winbase.h(5014): or       'BOOL
>   GetFileTime(HANDLE,LPFILETIME,LPFILETIME,LPFILETIME)' [found using
>   argument-dependent lookup] 1>          while trying to match the
>   argument list '(HANDLE, LPFILETIME, int, int)'

Comment: Если надо вызвать именно функцию из глобального пространства имен, то достаточно написать `::GetFileTime(`

Comment: Судя по другому вашему вопросу, у вас c++/cli. Поэтому используйте [FileInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас функция `GetFileTime` определена также в классе `Postup`, поэтому возникает неоднозначность. Вызовите ее вот так:

```
::GetFileTime(hFile, &ft, NULL, NULL);
```

Вообще это хорошая практика всегда указывать глобальное пространство имен `::`. Улучшает читаемость и предохраняет от таких вот ошибок.

Comment: СПАСИБО! Вы меня спасли!!!